# PhpMyAdmin Ubuntu 20 - password issue

Tags: apache2, mysql, password, phpmyadmin

I would like to install PhpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 20 server, but if I set the password while the installation process it throws me an error: Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements. I am sure the security level in Mysql is medium ([checked according this article](https://ostechnix.com/fix-mysql-error-1819-hy000-your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements/)) which means: Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, and special characters. Why this throws me an error? I dont understand.

Comment: Rule #1: never share your passwords.

Comment: Yes I know this is only test server and I want to avoid the questions like - Are you sure your password contains special chars?...

Answer (score 0):

As I found out: In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later versions), the root MySQL user is set to authenticate using the auth_socket plugin by default rather than with a password. This allows for some greater security and usability in many cases, but it can also complicate things when you need to allow an external program — like phpMyAdmin — to access the user.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04